# VB.NET I accidentally changed the generated Main

Tags: vb.net, program-entry-point, partial

I was messing around with multithreading earlier today, trying things, messing up, fixing them, etc. One of the exceptions thrown was at `app.Run()` and I didn't know if it was essential or not (now I do), so I put a `Try/Catch` around it to stop it from grinding to a halt every time.

Several hours later, I'm back to normal work, but I have an error and it is still acting like there's a `Try/Catch` around `app.Run()`.  The problem is now I can't find `app.Run()`.

Where is/can I modify the file that includes the auto generated partial Main (I think it ended in `g.i.vb`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the `bin`, `obj`, and `Generated_Code` folders, close VS and reopen and they will be re-built. See if that solves it. Don't mess with your designer files. Always save a copy or two of your projects then you can always revert back to the save one, and save often.

Comment: Is `Generated_Code` the same as `My Project`? I just want to be sure before messing anything up more.  And yeah your last few lines are good advice.  I just sometimes get careless because my hard drive is archived every six hours :)

Comment: I found the `g.i.vb` and `g.vb` files in my projects `obj` folder (in Windows Explorer), but rather than try and modify them more, I just deleted `obj` and it gave me my regular exceptions back! Thanks, I looked everywhere for that simple bit of information.